# Checking whether numbers can be found in a vector consecutively

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
avector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
num1 <- 1
num2 <- 2
num3 <- 3

num1%in%avector & num2%in%avector
# TRUE
```

I would like to write a similar line of code that is only `TRUE` if the numbers can be found in the `avector` consecutively.

Desired output:

```
num1%in%avector & num2%in%avector
# TRUE

# Code similar to this:
num1%in%vector & num3%in%vector
# FALSE
```

## EDIT:

**This was not included in the original question, but since I got so many answers.**

The reason that I was looking for a solution in the form of:

```
num1%in%vector & num3%in%vector
```

Is because I was hoping to use it to filter data (see `bonus_dat` below):

```
bonus_dat %>%
  filter(lower %in% strata[[1]] & upper %in% strata[[1]])
```

I have tried to apply the solution by Benson, but without succes:

```
bonus_dat %>%
  filter((lower %in% strata[[1]] & upper %in% strata[[1]] & (( which(strata[[1]] == lower) - which(strata[[1]] == upper)) == 1)  ))
```

Therefore a solution that can be used to filter rows has my preference.

## DATA:

```
library(dplyr)
bonus_dat <- structure(list(strata = list(c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), 
    c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 
    1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 
    1000, 1e+06), c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06)), lower = c(0L, 
25L, 100L, 500L, 500L, 1000L), upper = c(25L, 100L, 500L, 1000L, 
1000000L, 1000000L), value = c(1,3,4,6,2,1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    upper = c(25L, 100L, 500L, 1000L, 1000000L), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Please post a second question if needed

Comment: Use `rowwise()` before `filter()` and remove all `[[1]]`, your code will work. You could check my answer to see how to use `rowwise()` for filtering.

Comment: What about `bonus_dat %>% filter(match(upper, strata[[1]]) - match(lower, strata[[1]]) == 1L)`

Comment: @jblood94 The use of `[[1]]` means that this code cannot be vectorized and you only can take the first element of `strata`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, I don't believe so. Each of the 6 rows of `strata` is stored as a list of 1 element containing a vector (e.g., try `bonus_dat$strata[1]`). `[[1]]` is accessing that vector for each row. Besides, it seems to work when testing.

Comment: @jblood94 I was a bit skeptical too, but it worked for me without the `[[1]]`. You are saying it works with too?

Comment: @DarrenTsai, I can get it to work only with the `[[1]]`. I'll post a `reprex` as an answer.

Comment: @jblood94 your method works here because all elements of `strata` are the same in this case. The use of `strata[[1]]` means that all rows can only be compared with the first element of `strata`. Try this new data: `bonus_dat <- rbind(bonus_dat, tibble(strata = list(c(0, 10, 25, 50)), lower = 0, upper = 25, value = 7))`. The added row should be filtered out but your method keep it, right?.

Comment: The added row above should be filtered out because lower = 0 and upper = 25 are not consecutive in `c(0, 10, 25, 50)`. Your code make the added row compared with the first element of strata, i.e. `c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1000000)`, and of course it is kept. `strata` and `lower/upper` should be compared ***pairwisely***.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, makes sense. I edited my answer with `rowwise()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional AND statement: `abs(diff(match(c(x1, x2), vec))) == 1L`

```r
is.consec <- function(x1, x2, vec) {
  x1 %in% vec & x2 %in% vec & abs(diff(match(c(x1, x2), vec))) == 1L
}

is.consec(num1, num2, avector)
# [1] TRUE

is.consec(num1, num3, avector)
# [1] FALSE
```

Defining a custom function `is.consec()` is not necessary but it makes the codes neater.

---

The following test returns `FALSE` because 6 is not included in `avector`.

```r
is.consec(5, 6, avector)
# [1] FALSE
```

---

This method can be easily used to filter data:

```r
bonus_dat %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(is.consec(lower, upper, strata)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   strata    lower   upper value
#   <list>    <int>   <int> <dbl>
# 1 <dbl [6]>     0      25     1
# 2 <dbl [6]>    25     100     3
# 3 <dbl [6]>   100     500     4
# 4 <dbl [6]>   500    1000     6
# 5 <dbl [6]>  1000 1000000     1
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base` R, you can `paste` values to make a string and check if it is present:

```
grepl(paste(num1, num2, sep = ","), paste(avector, collapse = ","))
grepl(paste(num1, num3, sep = ","), paste(avector, collapse = ","))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use another expression to check if the difference in position is equal to 1, if it's equal to one, they're consecutive.

```
(num1 %in% avector & num2 %in% avector) & (abs(which(avector == num2) - which(avector == num1)) == 1)
[1] TRUE

(num1 %in% avector & num3 %in% avector) & (abs(which(avector == num3) - which(avector == num1)) == 1)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

How about pasting them together and using `str_detect`? This has the advantage of being easily extensible to an arbitrary number of numbers.

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(paste0(avector, collapse=""), paste0(c(num1, num2, num3), collapse=""))
```

```
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
avector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

num1 <- 1
num2 <- 2
num3 <- 3

diff(which(avector %in% c(num1, num2))) == 1
# TRUE

diff(which(avector %in% c(num1, num3))) == 1
# FALSE
```

**or with error handling**

```
avector <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

num1 <- 1
num2 <- 2
num3 <- 3

num4 <- 6

fun <- function(vec, nums) {
  if (!all(nums %in% avector)) stop("not all numbers are present in the vector")
  diff(which(vec %in% nums)) == 1)
}

fun(avector, c(num1, num2))
# [1] TRUE

fun(avector, c(num1, num3))
# [1] FALSE

fun(avector, c(num1, num4))
# Error in fun(avector, c(num1, num4)) : 
#   not all numbers are present in the vector
```

Comment: If `num1 <- 5` and `num2 <- 6`, it returns `logical(0)`. I think it's appropriate to return a `FALSE` because `6` cannot be found in the vector.

Comment: I leave the error handling to the OP, however if numbers are not present, it could also be argued it to be neither TRUE nor FALSE and for example return NA instead.

Comment: will update with error handling

Answer (score 1):

```
foo <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1L:(length(x) - 2L)) {
    if (x[i] == num1 && x[i + 1L] == num2 && x[i + 2L] == num3) return(TRUE)
  }  
}

foo(avector)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bonus_dat %>% rowwise() %>% filter(match(upper, strata) - match(lower, strata) == 1L)
```

seems to do the trick.

```
library(dplyr)

bonus_dat <- data.frame(lower = c(0L, 25L, 100L, 500L, 500L, 1000L, 400L),
                        upper = c(25L, 100L, 500L, 1000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 500L),
                        value = c(1,3,4,6,2,1,0))
bonus_dat$strata <- list(c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06),
                         c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06),
                         c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06),
                         c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06),
                         c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06),
                         c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06),
                         c(0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1e+06))
bonus_dat <- bonus_dat[, c(4, 1:3)]

bonus_dat %>% rowwise() %>% filter(match(upper, strata) - match(lower, strata) == 1L)
#>                           strata lower   upper value
#> 1 0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1000000     0      25     1
#> 2 0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1000000    25     100     3
#> 3 0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1000000   100     500     4
#> 4 0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1000000   500    1000     6
#> 5 0, 25, 100, 500, 1000, 1000000  1000 1000000     1
```